# Facebook follow page button non-plugin

Tags: facebook, api

I want to implement a custom facebook follow page button, without using a standart plugin. So I need to make a simple "follow specific page" api call. Is it possible, in the first place? Or using a plugin is the only solution?

Comment: No, it is not possible to follow a page via an API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Thanks CBroe for a confirmation